# Remove toolbar and reset collection on listing page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am using magento default loaded collection for category in some cases.So i would like to disable toolbar on that category.

I make that but when load category it display only product that is preset in category toolbar.

I have just change listing template and remove that toolbar from my listing template.

But toolbar has already set the product display limit so how can i reset display limit on my page.

Here is my collection code.

```
    <?php
namespace Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as jsondata;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    /*protected $jsonHelper;*/

    /*public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper)
    {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }*/
  protected $_productCollectionFactory;
  protected $priceCurrency;
  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        array $data = [],
        jsondata $jsonHelper,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility

    ) {
          $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data

        );
    }

    public function getProductCollectionData()
    {


    $_productCollection = $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple')->addTierPriceData();

   return $_productCollection
  }
```

I have tried to reset limit using

```
 $_productCollection->getSelect()->limit('all');
```

But not working.